# Add line to Shell Script File

Tags: bash, shell

How can I add a line to a shell script, at the very end of a function using bash?

Say the line I want to add is: `echo "Well Hello There";` and my function is

```
function hello_there {
    echo "Hi";
    echo "Whats popping?";

}
```

The only real constant will be the name of the method `hello_there`, and the beginning and end brackets... but I need the line to go above the end bracket... and I do not know how many times I will need to be able to do this...

Comment: Is this function in a text file, or are you trying to redeclare a function that's already in your environment? If it's in a file, are there other functions in the file? Will the function always consist of simple `echo` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not attempt to dynamically change the source of a script. It's too dangerous. There are several alternatives. The one closest to your problem specification would probably be to write the function like this:

```
function hello_there {
   echo "Hi";
   echo "Whats popping?";
   ${HELLO_THERE_POSTCMD:-true}
}
```

If you want to change the behaviour of this function, for example to have it recursively erase your home directory, you could set the environment variable

```
export HELLO_THERE_POSTCOMD="rm -rf $HOME"
```

before calling your script.

Comment: are you sure about posting `rm -rf $HOME` like this? note anyone: this will delete your home folder.

Comment: @sobolevn: Didn't you notice that I wrote this explicitly: **for example to have it recursively erase your home directory ....**. Eh - and just in case somebody did not get it: The general approach of my solution was meant seriously (I consider it much better than source code manipulation), but the concrete example was of course meant as a joke (I was not aware that nowadays jokes are recognized only if they have a suitable emoticon attached.....).

Comment: While appreciate the direction this answer takes, it does not answer the question and problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for the closing "}" and replace it with

```
printf '"Well Hello There"; \n}'
```

and insert a new line character after the semi colon, also use printf rather than echo

Comment: i could probably use `sed` for it?  something like `TMPVAR=$("echo 'Well Hello There';"); sed -i "s/}/$TMPVAR}/g"';`     ???  or is the end bracket a special character?

Comment: That might work, I dont think } is a special character but just escape it if it is

Comment: Tried `sed -i "s/}/chown $1:www-data /var/run/php/$1-*;\n}/g" /media/HOSTING/site-primer;`    also tried `sed -i "s/\}/chown $1:www-data /var/run/php/$1-*;\n\}/g" /media/HOSTING/site-primer;` Both return me `sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unknown option to `s'`

Answer (score 0):

You can regenerate function code as following :

```
function hello_there {
    echo "Hi";
    echo "Whats popping?";

}

cmd='echo \"Well\ Hello\ There \"'
type  hello_there |  tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e "s/.*nction/function/g"  | sed -e "s/[(|)]//g"  | sed -e "s/\}/\; $cmd\;\}/g"
```